# "Error on creating empty cart" Craft Commerce (Market Commerce)

Tags: plugins, ecommerce

When adding products to cart, was not getting same error in past but don't recalling changing anything. Using mostly default templates.

Comment: Sounds like a bug report to me, Dale. Can you send an email to support@craftcommerce.com along with specifics (version of Craft CMS, version of Craft Commerce, database dump, how to reproduce, etc.)?

Comment: Previously sent but will add more detail was just wondering if anyone else in the community may have encountered this.

Comment: I've hit that before with older versions of Market...not lately though